# Ubuntu keeps mounting as a read-only file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

My local work server went off after a series of powercuts, since then the filesystem is always mounted as a read-only file system. I have tried running fsck to fix the failed file system but after a while, it reverts back to read-only.

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Have you logged at /var/log/syslog for clues as to when/why it's going readonly?

Comment: I am getting this `kernel: [ 9506.578067] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_rename:3674: inode #53220844: comm dockerd: target of rename is already freed`

Comment: Look for the messages that occur at the exact time that the filesystem goes read-only.

Comment: It seems to be related to a docker issue, when docker is installed with snap. I was trying to install code-server and its related to this [issue](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/issues/540)